# Do computer science lab sections still have value for flipped courses?

Tags: teaching, computer-science

Many computer science courses consist of conventional lecture sections and lab sections. Typically, the lectures are "passive learning" experiences, and lab sections are where students actively solve problems.

Consider a flipped model, where, put simply, students experience lectures outside of class and solve problems during the "normal" lecture meetings. If students are actively solving problems during these sessions, what is the point of maintaining the typical lab section?

Comment: Wait, isn't that just renaming the "lab section" as "lecture"?

Comment: @John Do you mean renaming the "lecture" as "lab"? Perhaps, but I believe it goes deeper than this.

Comment: This kind of question would fit nicely at https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460/computer-science-educators (it's still in private beta, so you have to click "visit" from that page)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if there are lab sessions smaller than the normal lecture sessions then they still might have value, depending on what sorts of physical facilities you have.

One reason for the traditional labs is that students work in smaller groups. This gives them the opportunity for more individualized guidance than can occur in a huge lecture hall.

One advantage of the flipped classroom is that it enables small team and paired work under the view of an instructor. But labs can do this also. In such an environment students can answer a lot of their own questions themselves and don't get stuck waiting for assistance from a too busy instructor.

If you have appropriate facilities and lots of TAs to help with the flipped environment then you might be able to do without also using separate labs. But you probably want to organize it similarly to labs where a TA has an opportunity to know a small set of students and students "know" their TA. Otherwise separate labs seem to have little value.

You probably wouldn't find any advantage if you try to handle a large group on your own without providing smaller (i.e. lab) sessions).

Comment: Ah, the size aspect is important to consider.